# I am trying to create an event that occurs when the user clicks on a picture box that is created when the form loads

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an event that occurs when the user clicks on a picture box. The picture box is variable, picHandTwo is an array of 5 elements. It is created and instantiated in the form load. However, the event never occurs and the code inside doesn't execute

I've tried created a big transparent picturebox that runs over the entire form however, it covers all the images even when transparent.

```
Private Sub picHandTwo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim pt = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - 
        Me.Top)
        If lblStart.Visible = False Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(picHandTwo)
                If pt.X > picHandTwo(i).Left And pt.X < picHandTwo(i).Left + 
                   picHandTwo(i).Image.Width And pt.Y > picHandTwo(i).Top 
               And pt.Y < picHandTwo(i).Top + picHandTwo(i).Image.Height 
               Then
                    cardMagnifier.Image = handOne(i).getPic()
                End If
            Next
        End If
   End Sub
```

The code inside the method is fine and will occur but the event never happens. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Could you share the declaration of `picHandTwo`?

Comment: Do you handle the event by calling AddHandler ?

Comment: "It is created and instantiated in the form load. "  Show us your `Load()` event!

Comment: Also, you'll need to convert the SCREEN coords from Cursor.Position, to CLIENT coords.  As written, your "hit box" code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For an event to be handled, you need specifically add an event handler. This can be done in the form designer in Visual Studio or [by code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement). Something like:

`AddHandler event, AddressOf eventhandler`

In you case:

`AddHandler picHandTwo.Click, AddressOf picHandTwo_Click`

Comment: To be precise, the event is raised regardless of whether it is handled or not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm not sure about that. `RaiseEvent` may be called regardless of whether there are subscribers or not, (the invocation list is empty or not) but behind the scenes isn't it just doing the c# `Click?.Invoke(object, EventArgs);`. Isn't the invocation the actual raising?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions

1. If you want to handle the `Click` event instead of `MouseDown`, cast `EventArgs` to `MouseEventArgs` (those are actually the same object), so you have the relative mouse pointer location in `e.Location` (no need to translate the `Cursor.Position`)
2. Cast `sender` to `PictureBox` (`sender` references the control that generated the event), so you know which control has beed clicked. You can then access its properties directly.
3. Add the handler right after you have created the new Control, before adding it to another control's `Controls` collection.

Here, I'm also adding each new PictureBox to a `List(Of PictureBox)` (**`myPictureBoxes`**). It's not really need in this code, but it looks like you have something similar: **`handOne`**. Modify the code as needed.

```
Private myPictureBoxes As New List(Of PictureBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For x = 0 To 4
        Dim pbox = New PictureBox() With {
            .Size = New Size(80, 80),
            .Location = New Point(.Size.Width * x, 0),
            .Name = $"picHandTwo{x}"
        }
        AddHandler pbox.Click, AddressOf picHandTwo_Click
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pbox)
    Next
    For Each ctrl As Control In myPictureBoxes
        Me.Controls.Add(ctrl)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub picHandTwo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pbox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    If pbox Is Nothing Then Return
    ' If the Click location is needed: 
    Dim mousePos = DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).Location
    cardMagnifier.Image = pbox.Image
End Sub
```